# WPF window not shows properties of the base class

Tags: wpf, vb.net, inheritance, data-binding

I have a class that contains public property *MyDictionary*:

```
Public MustInherit Class MyBaseClass
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property MyDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Get
            Return New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {
                {0, "Option 1"},
                {1, "Option 2"}
            }
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

This class is a base class for few children classes, e.g. *ClassA* and *ClassB*. Property *MyDictionary()*, as expected, is inherited by children classes, but note, it's static.

Also I have a XAML markup like further, and control's DataContext is the instance of one of the children classes:

```
<Window>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ClassA}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary.Values}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem is while runtime the window contains blank ComboBox. Error description is:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'MyDictionary' property not found on 'object' ''ClassA'
>   (HashCode=9490272)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyDictionary.Values;
>   DataItem='ClassA' (HashCode=9490272); target element is
>   'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type
>   'IEnumerable')

If I explicitly override *MyDictionary()* property into *ClassA*, the problem is gone and ComboBox control contains items "Option 1" and "Option 2".

Two questions.

1. Why I need create properties in each children class for use it as control's items source? Why XAML can't use base class's properties? Value of inheritance is lost otherwise.
2. Is there way to use property of the base class as an items source?

Comment: Are you sure that ClassA is derived from MyBaseClass? Probably show us its declaration.

Comment: Also note that when you bind a ComboBox to a Dictionary, you usually bind `ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}"`, set `DisplayMemberPath="Value"`, `SelectedValuePath="Key"` and bind `SelectedValue="{Binding MySelectedKey}"`

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for notes. And sorry, I fogot mark that property is static. I've corrected this in the post.

Comment: Sure you really want to have a static property? All instances of derived classes would use the same Dictionary object. Is that what you intended? You wouldn't even need the base class. You could as well put the static property in some other class.

Comment: @Clemens You're right, of course. Probably, I must redesign my classes. You answered my 1st question. But what about second?

Comment: Works if the property isn't static. If it should be static, the Binding expression should look different. So is it supposed to be static or not?

Comment: @Clemens In current design it is static.

Comment: Then use static property binding syntax. See [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax#propertypath-for-objects-in-data-binding), section *Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified*: `"{Binding Path=(local:MyBaseClass.MyDictionary).Values}"`, where `local` might be replaced by the XAML namespace of your view models.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you very much! I've understood from your answers that incorrectly used binding to dictionary. Now I see how realize my project clearer, and as a consequence, i'll replace the static property with non-static.

Comment: @Clemens Maybe You may combine your answers and post it as the answer?..